# How to convert java.util.Date to java.sql.Date?

Tags: java, sql, datetime, date

I am trying to use a [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) as input and then creating a query with it - so I need a [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html).

I was surprised to find that it couldn't do the conversion implicitly or explicitly - but I don't even know how I would do this, as the Java API is still fairly new to me.

Comment: You can find a similar issue here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131068/error-casting-java-util-date-into-java-sql-date

Comment: For me, it turned out I didn't needed to convert. There was a `import java.sql.*` in my code, overriding the java.util.date and thus causing trouble when assigning date values that were fine with the latter but not the first. HTH

Comment: @DavidAckerman Do you understand that a java.util.Date is a date *and* a time-of-day, but a java.sql.Date is only a date *without* a time-of-day? (Actually there is a time-of-day but that is ignored, a bad hack of a class design) In SQL, `DATE` means date-only.

Comment: I indeed wasn't aware of the nuances back in '09, and since this question is so popular, I've changed the accepted answer to one that is both more modern and complete. Thanks everyone for your input!

Answer (score 135, accepted):

## tl;dr

> How to convert java.util.Date to java.sql.Date?

**Don’t.**

Both `Date` classes are outmoded. [Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Microsystems), [Oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle), and the [JCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Community_Process) community gave up on those legacy date-time classes years ago with the unanimous adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) defining the *java.time* classes.

- Use [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes instead of legacy `java.util.Date` & `java.sql.Date` with JDBC 4.2 or later.
- Convert to/from java.time if inter-operating with code not yet updated to java.time.

| Legacy | Modern | Conversion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `java.util.Date` | `java.time.Instant` | `java.util.Date.toInstant()` `java.util.Date.from( Instant )` |
| `java.sql.Date` | `java.time.LocalDate` | `java.sql.Date.toLocalDate()` `java.sql.Date.valueOf( LocalDate )` |

Example query with [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 
    … ,                                         // Specify the ordinal number of which argument in SQL statement.
    myJavaUtilDate.toInstant()                  // Convert from legacy class `java.util.Date` (a moment in UTC) to a modern `java.time.Instant` (a moment in UTC).
        .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )  // Adjust from UTC to a particular time zone, to determine a date. Instantiating a `ZonedDateTime`.
        .toLocalDate()                          // Extract a date-only `java.time.LocalDate` object from the date-time `ZonedDateTime` object.
)
```

Replacements:

- [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) instead of `java.util.Date`
  Both represent a moment in UTC. but now with nanoseconds instead of milliseconds.
- [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) instead of `java.sql.Date`
  Both represent a date-only value without a time of day and without a time zone.

## Details

If you are trying to work with date-only values (no time-of-day, no time zone), use the [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class rather than [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in the SQL standard.]

## java.time

In Java 8 and later, the troublesome old date-time classes bundled with early versions of Java have been supplanted by the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Much of the functionality has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

A [SQL data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Data_types) `DATE` is meant to be date-only, with no time-of-day and no time zone. Java never had precisely such a class† until [`java.time.LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) in Java 8. Let's create such a value by getting today's date according to a particular time zone (time zone is important in determining a date as a new day dawns earlier in Paris than in Montréal, for example).

```
LocalDate todayLocalDate = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );  // Use proper "continent/region" time zone names; never use 3-4 letter codes like "EST" or "IST".
```

At this point, we may be done. If your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) complies with [JDBC 4.2 spec](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221), you should be able to pass a `LocalDate` via [`setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-) on a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to store into a SQL DATE field.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , localDate );
```

Likewise, use [`ResultSet::getObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject-int-java.lang.Class-) to fetch from a SQL DATE column to a Java `LocalDate` object. Specifying the class in the second argument makes your code [type-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

```
LocalDate localDate = ResultSet.getObject( 1 , LocalDate.class );
```

In other words, **this entire Question is irrelevant under JDBC 4.2** or later.

If your JDBC driver does not perform in this manner, you need to fall back to converting to the java.sql types.

## Convert to java.sql.Date

To convert, use new methods added to the old date-time classes. We can call [`java.sql.Date.valueOf(…)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf-java.time.LocalDate-) to convert a `LocalDate`.

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf( todayLocalDate );
```

And going the other direction.

```
LocalDate localDate = sqlDate.toLocalDate();
```

## Converting from `java.util.Date`

While you should avoid using the old date-time classes, you may be forced to when working with existing code. If so, you can convert to/from java.time.

Go through the `Instant` class, which represents a moment on the timeline in UTC. An `Instant` is similar in idea to a `java.util.Date`. But note that `Instant` has a resolution up to [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) while `java.util.Date` has only [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) resolution.

To convert, use new methods added to the old classes. For example, [`java.util.Date.from( Instant )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-) and [`java.util.Date::toInstant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--).

```
Instant instant = myUtilDate.toInstant();
```

To determine a date, we need the context of a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. Apply a [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant ( instant , zoneId );
LocalDate localDate = zdt.toLocalDate();
```

---

† The java.sql.Date class pretends to be date-only without a time-of-day but actually *does* a time-of-day, adjusted to a midnight time. Confusing? Yes, the old date-time classes are a mess.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: "While you should avoid using the old date-time classes, you may be forced to when working with existing code. If so, you can convert to/from java.time."

Actually, no.  This and the the Date.valueOf() are actually **not** available in the JDBC/Java7 paradigm.

Comment: @sf_jeff Java 7 support is covered in the bullets at the end of my Answer: *Where to obtain the java.time classes?*

Comment: @Brain Reread *Convert to …* & *Converting from…* sections. To interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, do your business logic in *java.time*. At the edges convert between modern & legacy types by calling new methods added to the old classes. For `java.sql.Date`, see the [`toLocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Date.html#toLocalDate()) and [`valueOf( LocalDate )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf(java.time.LocalDate)) methods. Never write new code using the old classes.

Comment: I downvoted this answer, but not because it is incorrect. The OP asked how to do it, not for a browbeating over the use of legacy date objects or whether there was a better / newer way. For all Basil knows, the OP was constrained to an older version of java or a library that only allowed for those two types, yada yada yada.

Comment: @dnebing No browbeating intended. You may not realize just how terribly bad are the legacy date-time classes. Sun, Oracle, & the JCP community all gave up on these classes years ago with unanimous adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). The *java.time* classes come bundled with Java 8 and later.  All the legacy classes carry new methods for converting back-and-forth between legacy and modern objects. A back-port is available for Java 6 & 7, parallel API. That back-port is equipped with conversion methods as well. So there really is no reason to not be using *java.time*.

Comment: I know how bad they are. The OP probably knows how bad they are. The question wasn't about how bad they are, though, the question was just how to do it, and the answer should have stuck to that, IMHO. Don't get me wrong, your answer is absolutely right for the question "Should I still use java.util.Date or not?", so kudos for that.

Answer (score 531):

Nevermind....

```
public class MainClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
    System.out.println("utilDate:" + utilDate);
    System.out.println("sqlDate:" + sqlDate);

  }

}
```

explains it.  The link is http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/ConvertfromajavautilDateObjecttoajavasqlDateObject.htm

Comment: This is not an explicit conversion! From the Javadoc: "If the given milliseconds value contains time information, the driver will set the time components to the time in the default time zone (the time zone of the Java virtual machine running the application) that corresponds to zero GMT." So no matter what your time on your java.util.Date, it will be inserted as 00:00:00 in a column with the data type set to DATE.

Comment: @David Ackerman.....this method returns the `epochseconds` i.e milliseconds after `1,JAN,1970`. But What if we want to store the date of a person before this date....or something like `0000-00-00 as default`

Comment: In my case the correct answer is <code>java.sql.Timestamp sqlTimestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(utilDate.getTime());</code>, because it preserves the time fields.

Comment: @ArjunKP A java `long` can be assigned negative numbers, and that's negative numbers for in a Date.

Comment: It begs the question, why there are two different `Date` objects which are incompatible as part of java's design? Shouldn't it be named `SQLDate` or something instead of `Date`?

Comment: @wired00 Yes, the **old date-time classes** bundled with the early versions of Java **are a mess**, badly designed including some crude hacks. Whenever possible, try to use the new [java.time framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8 and later. These new classes supplant the old. The java.time classes and the old classes have some convenience methods for converting back and forth -- useful while we wait for JDBC drivers to be updated to directly utilize the new java.time types.

Comment: @BasilBourque thanks very much on java.time will check into it

Comment: @wired00 See [my new Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31238011/642706) on this Question for how to use java.time. Also search StackOverflow for many more examples.

Answer (score 41):

With the other answer you may have troubles with the time info (compare the dates with unexpected results!)

I suggest:

```
java.util.Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date(); // your util date
cal.setTime(utilDate);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);    
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(cal.getTime().getTime()); // your sql date
System.out.println("utilDate:" + utilDate);
System.out.println("sqlDate:" + sqlDate);
```

Comment: If he's using java.sql.Date for a Date column in a database, that time information will be truncated. You've overengineered the solution in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, maybe I did it. I sometimes need to compare the java.sql.Data with the current date and imho this is the best way. I hope it can help.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Of course, this topic was about 10 yrs ago, pre-java 8.

Answer (score 33):

This function will return a converted SQL date from java date object.

```
public java.sql.Date convertJavaDateToSqlDate(java.util.Date date) {
    return new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Converting `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date` will lose hours, minutes and seconds. So if it is possible, I suggest you to use `java.sql.Timestamp` like this:

```
prepareStatement.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(utilDate.getTime()));
```

For more info, you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305973/java-util-date-vs-java-sql-date).

Answer (score 17):

In my case of picking date from JXDatePicker (java calender) and getting it stored in database as SQL Date type, below works fine ..

`java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(pickedDate.getDate().getTime());`

where pickedDate is object of JXDatePicker

Answer (score 6):

This function will return a converted SQL date from java date object.

```
public static java.sql.Date convertFromJAVADateToSQLDate(
            java.util.Date javaDate) {
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = null;
        if (javaDate != null) {
            sqlDate = new Date(javaDate.getTime());
        }
        return sqlDate;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Format your java.util.Date first. Then use the formatted date to get the date in java.sql.Date

```
java.util.Date utilDate = "Your date"
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
final String stringDate= dateFormat.format(utilDate);
final java.sql.Date sqlDate=  java.sql.Date.valueOf(stringDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here the example of converting Util Date to Sql date and ya this is one example what i am using in my project might be helpful to you too.

```
java.util.Date utilStartDate = table_Login.getDob();(orwhat ever date your give form obj)
java.sql.Date sqlStartDate = new java.sql.Date(utilStartDate.getTime());(converting date)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am a novice: after much running around this worked.  Thought might be useful

```
     String bufDt =  bDOB.getText();  //data from form
     DateFormat dF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); //data in form is in this format
     Date bbdt = (Date)dF.parse(bufDt);  // string data is converted into java util date
     DateFormat dsF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); //converted date is reformatted for conversion to sql.date
     String ndt = dsF.format(bbdt); // java util date is converted to compatible java sql date
     java.sql.Date sqlDate=  java.sql.Date.valueOf(ndt);  // finally data from the form is convered to java sql. date for placing in database
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

Method for comparing 2 dates (util.date or sql.date)

```
 public static boolean isSameDay(Date a, Date b) {
    Calendar calA = new GregorianCalendar();
    calA.setTime(a);

    Calendar calB = new GregorianCalendar();
    calB.setTime(b);

    final int yearA = calA.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    final int monthA = calA.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int dayA = calA.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

    final int yearB = calB.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    final int monthB = calB.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int dayB = calB.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

    return yearA == yearB && monthA == monthB && dayA == dayB;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
public static String toMysqlDateStr(Date date) {
    String dateForMySql = "";
    if (date == null) {
        dateForMySql = null;
    } else {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        dateForMySql = sdf.format(date);
    }

    return dateForMySql;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way to convert is:

```
static java.sql.Timestamp SQLDateTime(Long utilDate) {
    return new java.sql.Timestamp(utilDate);
}

Date date = new Date();
java.sql.Timestamp dt = SQLDateTime(date.getTime());
```

If you want to insert the `dt` variable into an SQL table you can do:

```
insert into table (expireAt) values ('"+dt+"');
```

Comment: This appears to be essentially the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31237429/1711796) posted a year earlier.

Answer (score -3):

i am using the following code please try it out

```
DateFormat fm= new SimpleDateFormatter();
```

specify the format of the date you want
for example `"DD-MM_YYYY"` or `'YYYY-mm-dd'`  then use the java Date datatype as

```
fm.format("object of java.util.date");
```

then it will parse your date

Answer (score -4):

You can use this method to convert util date to sql date,

```
DateUtilities.convertUtilDateToSql(java.util.Date)
```

Comment: There's no DateUtilities class in the standard Java library (and I can't even find this method anywhere at all from a quick Google search). If this is from a specific library, you might want to say as much and include a link to the docs.

Answer (score -4):

I was trying the following coding that worked fine.

> java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
>  java.sql.Date
>   sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate);

Answer (score -8):

If you are usgin Mysql a date column can be passed a String representation of this date

so i using the DateFormatter Class to format it and then set it as a String in the sql statement or prepared statement

here is the code illustration:

```
private String converUtilDateToSqlDate(java.util.Date utilDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String sqlDate = sdf.format(utilDate);
    return sqlDate;
}
```

String date = converUtilDateToSqlDate(otherTransaction.getTransDate());

//then pass this date in you sql statement

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, I have a few comments to your answer. The question was "how to convert a java.util.Date to java.sql.Date". The code you pasted formats a java.util.Date as yyyy-MM-dd. This is actually of limited use in this context since you should pass the java.sql.Date directly to the jdbc drivers instead of doing it as a string.