# How can I save string type into android SQLite datetime field

Tags: android, sqlite

I've got following string **"2013-04-30T00:55:25.855-07:00"** from Google blogger feed. I try to save this string to SQLite datetime field as following command

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
initialValues.put(newsdatemodified, dateFormat.format(datemodified));
```

But I found that data cannot insert into sqlite table and no encounter any errors. Any solution will be appreciated.

## Update

When I've tried to use following coding

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
Date date1 = (Date) dateFormat.parse(entry.updated);
```

but following this error

```
05-02 09:56:05.383: E/AndroidRuntime(31634): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
```

Comment: what is entry? (entry.updated)

Comment: Entry format is "2013-04-30T00:55:25.855-07:00". I got it from Blogger Feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that issue is with the format. May be, you can try using `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`. `SSS` stands for fractional seconds and `Z` stands for time zone.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

Hope it helps else please comment. You can see other formats and try to work around with them by seeing [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: following this error 05-02 09:56:05.383: E/AndroidRuntime(31634): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date

Comment: Try casting it as [follows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530012/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date). See if this works.

Answer (score 2):

Your format is wrong, it needs to me  `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

as you can see the format you had does not match what the incoming string format was