# Converting String into SQl Date format

Tags: java, oracle, postgresql, jdbc

I need to load data from Postgres to Oracle. While reading data from Postgres I got the date in below format "2013-02-13 00:30:22.402" now I need to load this date into oracle db 
I tried but getting exception

```
String dd = "2013-02-13 00:30:22.402";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
java.sql.Date dateform=(Date) formatter.parse(dd);
System.out.println(dateform);
```

**Throws this exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
    at ghg.main(ghg.java:26)
```

Comment: [how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530012/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date)

Comment: Why do you use Strings at all? If you do a `getTimestamp` on one side and then a `setTimestamp()` on the other side, you don't need any conversion at all

Comment: I want to store the data in exact format along with time and seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this

```
java.util.Date date = formatter.parse(dd);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

parse returns a `java.util.Date`, so you need to construct a new sql Date object using the constructor `new Date(long l)` :

```
java.sql.Date dateform= new java.sql.Date(formatter.parse(dd).getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

by default parse function return a Date object. so you can not cast return value.

> Date  parse(String source)
>   Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a date.

```
             String dd = "2013-02-13 00:30:22.402";
             DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
             java.sql.Date dateform=formatter.parse(dd);
```