# how to sent date as parameter to get records from database

Tags: android

I want to get records from database for last 1 week. I take current date and the date 7 days before and I send them to the database handler but it returns error:

```
The method `getALLCompJobs(String, String)` in the type `DatabaseHandler` is not applicable for 
the `arguments (Date, Date)`
```

Below is my code. Please, help me to figure out how to get records for the past week from the database.

```
           public class JobSchema extends BackBaseActivity {

            Date dateBefore7day;
        Date CurrentDate;


         @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.jobsschema);
             Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

             SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy   HH:mm");
        df.format(c.getTime());
       CurrentDate=c.getTime();
               c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);

              dateBefore7day=  c.getTime();



                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(JobSchema.this);
            jobarr = db.getALLCompJobs(CurrentDate,dateBefore7day);


         <---error show  The method getALLCompJobs(String, String) in the type 
       DatabaseHandler is not applicable for the arguments (Date, Date) --?


        public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

              String CREATE_COMPLETED_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_COMPLETED_JOBS
            + "(" + KEY_COMPID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TIMEJOB
            + " TEXT," + KEY_TIMEWEEK+ " DATE,"    + KEY_PICK + " 
                          TEXT," + KEY_DEST + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_FARE + " TEXT" + ")";


                  public List<JobSchmeModel> getALLCompJobs(String CurrentDate, String 
          dateBefore7day) {
//public List<JobSchmeModel> getALLCompJobs() {
    List<JobSchmeModel> compjobsList = new ArrayList<JobSchmeModel>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_COMPLETED_JOBS + " WHERE "  
      + KEY_TIMEWEEK + ">=" + dateBefore7day + " AND " + KEY_TIMEJOB + "<=" + 
       CurrentDate + " ORDER BY "+KEY_COMPID+" DESC";
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

Comment: you need to pass date as string in `getALLCompJobs(..)`.

Comment: and how i will qeury for recoreds from database??? if i pass dates as string it will get records from database??

Comment: yes, but make sure your date fields with data type `DATETIME` as i tell you last time if you remember.

Comment: but in my database i m using only date for saving date in database check above

Comment: + KEY_TIMEWEEK+ " DATE,"   check this u mean change this to "DateTIME

Comment: Yes use `DATETIME` for both KEY_TIMEWEEK and KEY_TIMEJOB.

Comment: I've posted an answer that should solve you issue. But consider this: this is not really the kind of issue you should ask help with on SO. This is basic, entry-level Java knowlede and simple attention to what compiler says. You absolutely have to learn some basics -- at least read a book on Java (e.g. _Thinking in Java_ by _Bruce Ekkel_ is a good one) -- before you ask questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If your language supports it, you can use a form of date called "epochtime" (number of seconds since 1 Jan, 1970).  Simple arithmetic adding or subtracting seconds from the date in this form is very effective.

Answer (score 0):

Well, read the error: it's telling you you're passing parameters of wrong type to your `getALLCompJobs` method. It takes `String` parameters, what you're passing it are of type `Calendar`. Try this

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy   HH:mm");
String sCurrent = df.format(c.getTime());
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);
String sWeekBefore = df.format(c.getTime());
jobarr = db.getALLCompJobs(sCurrent, sWeekBefore);
```

UPD
The format of the date string doesn't look right.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/530022/375929) for how to convert `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date` and don't forget to call `.toString()` on the date objects you pass to `db.getALLCompJobs(...)`

Comment: I assumed you know your way around your sql. Is the sql query you use not giving you the needed entries?

I'm no SQL expert, but I think it's the problem with your format string.

Look at this answer for how to produce SQL-ready date object.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/530022/375929