# How to cast java.util.date to java.sql.date?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, casting

```
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
     try {
         date = dt.parse("2014-03-14");
     } catch (ParseException parseException) {
     }
    orderBean.setDate((java.sql.Date) date);
```

when I try to cast util.date to sql.date using above code an error occurs as below. I am using mysql data base to store a data.
can anyone help me?

```
Mar 14, 2014 11:16:44 AM gui.salespot jButton1ActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), `java.sql.Date`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**. You cannot cast different type of Objects like that.

instead you can get the time which is `long` and use it.

```
java.sql.Date sDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

Answer (score 2):

try this way

```
Date date = new Date();
java.sql.Date d=new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

`java.sql.Date` extends from `java.util.Date`, so you can case `java.sql.Date` to `java.util.Date` but not the other way round.

Try using...

```
orderBean.setDate(new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
```

Instead...

Comment: almost all the answers are upvoted except yours though your answer has good explanations,+1 from my side

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.Date` is superclass of `java.sql.Date` you can not type cast it by this way.

try with - `java.sql.Date#Date(long)`

Snippet -

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime())
```

Answer (score 0):

*look like simple....*

```
public class MainClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
    System.out.println("utilDate:" + utilDate);
    System.out.println("sqlDate:" + sqlDate);

  }
}
```

explains it. The link is [click](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/ConvertfromajavautilDateObjecttoajavasqlDateObject.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Use this answer to convert date.

```
java.util.Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date(); // your util date
cal.setTime(utilDate);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);    
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(cal.getTime().getTime()); // your sql date
System.out.println("utilDate:" + utilDate);
System.out.println("sqlDate:" + sqlDate);
```

For your concern copy my code.

```
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
     try {
         date = dt.parse("2014-03-14");
     } catch (ParseException parseException) {
     }
      orderBean.setDate(new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4097430/2722799) reference.. Thanks..