# Converting String date to java.sql.Date

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

Please advise how can I convert the **date** that I am getting in `String` form 
to `java.sql.Date` form..

```
String Dateimp = abcObject.getabcDate();
java.sql.Date  sd = ?????  // what should i write in here.
```

at last finally i want to convert the date that I am getting in String form to java.sql.Date

Comment: I'd be the same process as converting a `String` to a `java.util.Date`...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can you please post the code so that I can grasp

Comment: Search "Java String to Date" - there are literally thousands of examples.  The question will be, what format is `Dateimp` in...

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion?rq=1 combined with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530012/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date?rq=1

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.sql.Date` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4):

You need to know the exact format of your string, for intance if your date is formatted as "2014-01-30",

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
java.util.Date date = df.parse(Dateimp);
// if you really need java.sql.Date
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

Read how to build the date pattern here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    Date parsedate = format.parse(YOUR STRING DATE);
    java.sql.Date sql = new java.sql.Date(parsedate.getTime());
```

Last line will convert your Date object to SQL Date.

Answer (score 2):

//This convert the string to Date

```
  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String dateInString = "7-Jun-2013";

try {

    Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

/* Below code snippet convert a java util Date into a sql Date for use in databases */

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly retrieve it some thing like

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
java.sql.Date sql;
java.util.Date date;

try {
    Date today = df.parse(rs.getString("date"));
    date= new java.util.Date();
      sql= new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());

} catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The date in "sql" can use for the db conversations