# java date to sql date type conversion

Tags: java, sql, casting

I am trying to convert a java date object to sql date object. I tried to implement something on my own and came up with the following:

```
try {
    rs.updateDate("", (java.sql.Date) new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(jTextFieldDate.getText()));
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(helpdesk.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Here **rs** is a `Result Set` object and **jTextFieldDate** as the name suggests is a java text field object. Is this implementation correct. What are the possible problems i may encounter by using this code.....

Comment: Casting is not a conversion - it only works if the target type and the actual type are related in terms of class hierarchies and implemented interfaces, i.e. if the actual type _already is_ the target type. You need a mapping, not a cast.

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530012/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work. You cannot cast a `java.util.Date` (returned by the `parse` method of `SimpleDateFormat`) to `java.sql.Date`. To convert the `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date`, you can do the following:

```
try {
    java.util.Date utilDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(jTextFieldDate.getText());
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
    rs.updateDate("", sqlDate);
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(helpdesk.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
 new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(jTextFieldDate.getText()))
```

returns a `java.util.Date` not a `java.sql.Date`

You can construct a `java.sql.Date` using a `long tm` which you can from `java.util.Date.getTime ()`