# getting Class Cast Exception while sending date to DAO Class

Tags: java

```
// I am trying to send date to my dao class but i am getting exception    
    String dateInString = request.getParameter("date");
                Date date = null;

                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                try {
// i am importing java.sql.Date
                  //i am getting java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
                    date = (Date) sdf.parse(dateInString);
                } catch (ParseException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                LeaveBalance leave = new LeaveBalance(associateID, date,
                        bufferApplicable, buffer);
                assoicatesDAO = new AssociatesDAO();
                boolean success = assoicatesDAO.leaveBalance(leave);
                if (success) {
                    msg = "Associate's leave has been added successfully.";
                } else {
                    msg = "****";
                }
                request.setAttribute("responseMessage", msg);
                dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/success.jsp");
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);

            }
```

Comment: Import java.util.Date instead?

Comment: Check what format date your are receiving form "date" parameter

Comment: or explicitly cast to java.util.Date -> date = (java.util.Date) sdf.parse(dateInString);

Comment: `java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(sdf.parse(dateInString).getTime()); `

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530012/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date?lq=1?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `java.util.Date` as `SimpleDateFormat` deals with `java.util.Date` and *not* `java.sql.Date`.

Answer (score 2):

cast exception is Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance.

So, for example, when one tries to cast an Integer to a String, String is not an subclass of Integer, so a ClassCastException will be thrown.

```
Object i = Integer.valueOf(42);
String s = (String)i;            // ClassCastException thrown here.
```

here in your code you should

```
import java.util.Date;

     date = sdf.parse(dateInString); //thanks to @ Mustafa sabir
```

Comment: Explicit cast of `(Date)` is not required, `parse()` returns type of `java.util.Date`

Comment: @Mustafasabir but the code now is working for me? still if You say i will try that.

Comment: @DeepanshuBedi The topic of this question implies a learning programmer, the explanation is good to have. In the  event OP understands the exception, he can reference the other answers anyway. :)

Comment: Yes it will work, but even if you remove it will work , its not wrong, just that you are giving cast of the same type to the same object, which is redundant :)

Comment: Thumbs up, had to try before implementing it. @Mustafasabir

Answer (score 1):

use import `java.util.Date` instead of `java.sql.Date`

```
SimpleDateFormatObject.parse()
```

will return Date of type `java.util.Date` so in that case you will never need to cast it as you are doing in here

```
date = (Date) sdf.parse(dateInString);
```

Answer (score 0):

java.sql.Date is a subclass of java.util.Date. This means that sql.Date contains more details than it's superclass (it is more specialized). This is why you cannot cast a util.Date to a sql.Date: there is no way for the JVM to 'fill in the blanks'. The other way around is not a problem.

For a solution, you could import java.util.Date instead of java.sql.Date, or, if that breaks other part of the code, simply use the fully qualified class name in your code:

```
java.util.Date date = null;
// etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `import` declaration of this class is `java.sql.Date`. As `SimpleDateFormat.parse(String)` returns `java.util.Date`, you may have to import the proper `Date` from `java.util` instead.

However in the event that `java.sql.Date` is required for the rest of your code and you must keep the import declaration as same, change the following:

```
{
    // Declare date as proper Date
    java.util.Date date = null;

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    try {
        /* // Cast to proper Date
         * date = (java.util.Date) sdf.parse(dateInString);
         * This cast is actually redundant, so just use:
         */
        date = sdf.parse(dateInString);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `Date date` variable is of type `java.sql.Date` , while the `sdf.parse()` returns `java.util.Date`.Hence the exception at `date=sdf.parse(..)` . Import `java.util.Date` instead of `java.sql.Date`