# JCalendar to sql.Date not working

Tags: java, date, calendar, datepicker

Trying to enter dates into a database, got a JDatePicker(datecEventDate) and need to need its date and it to a database

```
java.sql.Date EventDate = datecEventDate.getDate();
```

This doesnt seem to work and have tried other variations
 I need help converting the util.Date type to sql.Date

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert java.util.date to java.sql.date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530012/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned elsewhere, it is quite easy to convert from a java.util.Date to a java.sql.Date:

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```