# java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date

Tags: java, oracle, servlets

I am trying to insert Date into Database but I am getting error as  java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date.
Please help.

```
String next_dt = req.getParameter("NextDate");
DateFormat dtFmt = null;
dtFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
dtToday = (Date) dtFmt.parse(next_dt);
```

Comment: That's cause `java.util.Date` isn't a child of `java.sql.Date`, it's the other way round.  I believe you can use `new java.sql.Date(dtToday.getTime());`

Comment: `sqlDate = new Date(javaDate.getTime());` I think dtToday is the date you want to insert. you need to convert it to sql date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static java.sql.Date convertFromJAVADateToSQLDate(
        java.util.Date javaDate) {
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = null;
    if (javaDate != null) {
        sqlDate = new Date(javaDate.getTime());
    }
    return sqlDate;
}
```

As the name of the class is same use should give fully qualified name(FQN) of both classes you also can use format method to convert date to proper SQL format date.

```
public static String toMysqlDateStr(Date date) {
String dateForMySql = "";
if (date == null) {
    dateForMySql = null;
} else {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    dateForMySql = sdf.format(date);
}

return dateForMySql;
```

}

Answer (score 4):

You have imported `java.sql.Data`. But `dtFmt.parse(next_dt);` returns an object of type `java.util.Date` so you have to change

```
import java.sql.Date;
```

to

```
import java.util.Date;
```

Comment: I tried that too but then i am not able to insert dtToday  into table.

Comment: If you need the date for sql statements, you have to convert the `java.Util.Date`to an `java.sql.Date` See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530012/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date) how you can do it.

Answer (score 2):

Add following lines - as it needs to be a sql Date and not util date

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(dtToday.getTime());
//now insert this sqlDate
```

Answer (score 1):

[`DateFormat.parse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) returns a `java.util.Date`, and you're trying to illegally cast it to a `java.sql.Date`.

Assuming you continue to import `java.sql.Date`, you can successfully assign the variable like so:

```
dtToday = new Date(dtFmt.parse(next_dt).getTime());
```

Comment: Still not able to insert in database..

Answer (score 1):

You should use `java.sql.Timestamp` or `java.sql.Date` instead of `java.util.Date`
Problem with `java.sql.Date` is that it will not store time. So using Timestamp is the approach i always take. As it is the child class of `java.util.date` it is compatible with both date and timestamp columns in DB.