# convert a String date of format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" to * java.util.Date of format dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss

Tags: simpledateformat, java-6

```
/**
 * 
 * Purpose:
 * 
 * 1. Need to convert a String date of format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" to
 * java.util.Date of format dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss and convert that to
 * java.sql.Date to send to database table column of type Date.
 *
 */
public class TestDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String inputDateStr = "10-Jan-2013";
        SimpleDateFormat inputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat outputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        java.util.Date inputDateDate = inputFormatter.parse(inputDateStr);
        System.out.println("inputDateDate :" + inputDateDate);
        // printed: inputDateDate :Thu Jan 10 00:00:00 EST 2013

        String requiredDateStr = outputFormatter.format(inputDateDate);
        System.out.println("requiredDateStr :" + requiredDateStr);
        // printed: requiredDateStr :10/01/2013 00:00:00

        /*
         * PROBLEM: Need to convert this 'requiredDateStr' ie: '10/01/2013
         * 00:00:00' to a java.util.Date type and still retain the pattern of
         * "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
         */

        //how to do this?

        // java.util.Date requiredDateDate = feeding requiredDateStr and format
        // of "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

        // java.sql.Date sqlDate = new Date(requiredDateDate.getTime());

    }
}
```

Edit: Question: How to convert this String "10/01/2013 00:00:00" to `java.util.Date` format?

Ultimately I want to convert this String "10/01/2013 00:00:00" to a `java.sql.Date` format

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. You say you want a java.util.Date of a specific format, but java.util.Date isn't in any format at all; it's just a specific instant in time (measured in milliseconds since the epoch)

Comment: @Jens edited the post to add the exact question

Comment: @ComputerDruid you opened my eyes.. Thank you for that information. Yes, I was trying to get a Date of a specific format which is not possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SimpleDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss") ;
df.parse("10/01/2013 00:00:00");
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more Information about the Format.

For your second question see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530012/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date).

Comment: Thanks for the link for my second qn. First one doesn't help me as it gives a Date of some format, where as I was looking for Date of a particular format. For the first one,  ComputerDruid well said. If you can append that to your answer, I can accept yours and close this. Thank you for helping me

Comment: @spiderman it gives you the date for the Format you asking for?!

Comment: No it doesn't. `java.util.Date` will not. thats what he was explaining

Comment: I was referring to this comment of @ComputerDruid "java.util.Date isn't in any format at all; it's just a specific instant in time (measured in milliseconds since the epoch) "

Comment: @spiderman yes i know. I am not sure what hat this too du with your question? `Question: How to convert this String "10/01/2013 00:00:00" to java.util.Date format?`

Comment: Sorry for that, my question title gives more clarity - How to convert this String "10/01/2013 00:00:00" to java.util.Date of the  format 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss' . If I just do a parse on the dateString, I get a java.util.Date of some format, not exactly in 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss'