# How to store time from java.util.Date into java.sql.Date

Tags: java, date

I want to convert `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date` but I want hours, minutes, and seconds as well but java.sql.Date can be used only to store date(no time) . I tried the below code but it is giving only year, month, and day for the `java.sql.Date` object.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
Date parsed = format.parse("20110210120534");
System.out.println(format.parse("20110210120534"));
java.sql.Date sql = new java.sql.Date(parsed.getTime());
System.out.println("SQL date is= "+sql);
```

Current output:

```
2011-02-10
```

Desired output:

```
2011-02-10 12:05:34
```

Comment: Purpose of `java.sql.Date` precisely to store only informations about date, not about time (we have `java.sql.Time` for that). What are you really trying to achieve? Why are you want to use `java.sql.Date` instead of `java.util.Date`?

Comment: Use `java.sql.Timestamp` instead of `java.sql.Date` if you want more precision.

Comment: Thanks, I used Timestamp to resolve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert java.util.Date to java.sql.Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530012/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date)

Comment: @Vadzim I had to search quite a bit to find the SQL part in that question / answer and then I had to look for time handling as well. I've changed the title instead of voting to close to indicate that this is specific for the time stored in `java.util.date`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) type is used to store only date (no time) information, as it maps to the SQL `DATE` type, which doesn't store time. What its [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString%28%29) method does is:

> Formats a date in the date escape format yyyy-mm-dd.

To achieve the desired output you can use [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html), which stores date **and** time information, mapping to the SQL `TIMESTAMP` type. Its [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toString%28%29) method outputs what you need:

> Formats a timestamp in JDBC timestamp escape format: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fffffffff, where ffffffffff indicates nanoseconds.

Example:

```
java.text.DateFormat format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
java.util.Date date = format.parse("20110210120534");
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
System.out.println(timestamp); // prints "2011-02-10 12:05:34.0"
```

Answer (score 5):

As other folks said, you need to use java.sql.TimeStamp.

```
public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
            java.sql.Timestamp sqlTimeStamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
            System.out.println("util-date:" + date);
            System.out.println("sql-timestamp:" + sqlTimeStamp );

        }

}
```

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-sql-date.html