# Inserting date into SQL server from Java - not formatting properly

Tags: java, sql-server, date, datetime

I am trying to insert a date into a SQL table in a specific format. I am successfully inserting the date into a column of type `datetime`, but the formatting is incorrect.

I have the following:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
df.setTimeZone(tz);
String timeString = df.format(System.currentTimeMillis());
Date date = df.parse(timeString);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

I can see that `timeString` is being set correctly to a string like : "`2017-01-11 18:19:06.662`"

but date then gets set to something like: "`Wed Jan 11 13:19:06 EST 2017`" (missing milliseconds)

and `sqlDate` gets set to "`2017-01-11`"

when I look at the table to see what the value is, I see that for the field I'm setting, I'm seeing that the `datetime` gets set to "`2017-01-11 00:00:00.000`".

Now this is missing all of the time info, which I'm sure has to do with the fact that `sqlDate` gets set to a value with no time, but Im not sure why sql date has no time value. I looked at some older posts that tried dealing with the same, but found no resolution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29392755/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320378/how-do-i-format-a-java-sql-date-into-this-format-mm-dd-yyyy).

Suggestions on why this may be happening are appreciated.

Comment: You are missing the timezone setting in the format. Try including it in the mask and set it that way

Comment: What is your table definition for the column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to be correct, you only get confused due to the implementation of `toString`:

1. In `java.util.Date` which gives the date to the form `dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy`.
2. In `java.sql.Date` which gives the date to the form `yyyy-mm-dd`.

But if you compare what `getTime()` returns for both (`date` and `sqlDate`), you will get the same value as what you initially provided to `df.format` to get `timeString`.

---

Your mistake is more that you use `java.sql.Date` for a datetime because as stated into the javadoc:

> To conform with the definition of `SQL DATE`, the millisecond values
>   wrapped by a `java.sql.Date` instance must be **'normalized' by setting
>   the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero** in the
>   particular time zone with which the instance is associated.

You are supposed to use [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) instead of `java.sql.Date` to keep the time part of your date (hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds) as you expect.

Your code should then be:

```
...
java.sql.Timestamp sqlDate = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

Comment: Thank you this worked! Thank you for the explanation as well.