# Java String to Date

Tags: java, string, datetime, callable-statement

I have a Stored Procedure that requires the following input parameters -

```
PROCEDURE `Report_Publishing`(p_StartDate datetime, p_EndDate dateTime, p_Action varchar(15))
```

From the Frontend I am getting the start and end dates in following format -
`start as a String "2017-03-15"` and `end as a String "2017-04-17"`,

Following is the piece of code, to convert the start and end dates into the Stored Procedure's required format -

```
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; 

public List<PublishReportDto> getExport(String start, String end, String action, Connection conn, String sql) {
        List<PublishReportDto> publishList = null;

        try {
            CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(sql);

            start += " 00:00:00";
            end += " 00:00:00";
            Date startDate = null;
            Date endDate = null;
            try {
                startDate = (Date) new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(start);
                endDate = (Date) new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(end);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            cs.setDate(1,(java.sql.Date) startDate);
            cs.setDate(2,(java.sql.Date) endDate);
            cs.setString(3, action);
            cs.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.DATE);
            cs.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.DATE);
            cs.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
```

**I am getting the following Exception -**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
```

**Modifications -**
**Replaced -** 
1. `import java.sql.Date` with **import java.util.Date;**

2.

```
cs.setDate(1,startDate);
cs.setDate(2,endDate);
```

by

```
cs.setDate(1,(java.sql.Date) startDate);
cs.setDate(2,(java.sql.Date) endDate);
```

Now I'm getting -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
```

**Can someone please help me out?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert from `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date` by using the constructor of the `java.sql.Date`:

> **Date(long date)**  //constructor of the java.sql.Date
>
> Constructs a Date object using the given milliseconds
>   time value.

to get the start date:

```
Date startDate = new java.sql.Date(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(start).getTime());
```

to get the end date:

```
Date endDate = new java.sql.Date(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(end).getTime());
```

**note** - in the future If you are going to be working with date-only values you should use the **[`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)** class rather than `java.util.Date`.

Comment: Hi your solution worked, though now I'm getting the following Exception -  java.sql.SQLException: Parameter number 1 is not an OUT parameter

Answer (score 2):

You can try implementing something in your code like this:

```
String string = "January 2, 2010";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = format.parse(string);
System.out.println(date);
```

Date will parse the string that you put in and then it will give you teh correct date hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You've imported the wrong `Date`. Notice you've imported `java.sql.Date` which corresponds to the cast `(Date)`, change that import to `java.util.Date` and it should work.

`SimpleDateFormat.parse()` returns an instance of `java.util.Date` which is *different* from `java.sql.Date` and you cannot cast from one to the other. It is possible to [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29392755/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date) if you really need a `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: that solved the exception but, now my startDate contains -> Wed Mar 15 00:00:00 IST 2017 , will this format satisfy my Stored Procedure's input format?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the (java.util.Date)Date obj into java.sql.Date  constructor

```
java.util.Date startDate = new java.util.Date();
            java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(startDate.getTime());
```