# How to covert date variable to java.sql.date

Tags: java

I am facing difficulties while trying to insert a date variable into a database table. My variable is called:

```
Date date4;
```

The date4 variable value is read from a textbox which has a calendar picker. For inserting in a date column, I am setting the field type to date:

```
preparedstmt.setDate(4,date4);
```

However, I got the below message after submitting the form:

javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert 4/1/15 12:00 AM of type class java.util.Date to class java.sql.Date

Also, is there a way to insert the field in the format of date ("dd-MON-YYYY")?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered many times before on this site and elsewhere, q.v. [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530012/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date) for example.

Comment: Can I insert the format of date ("dd-MON-YYYY") in a date column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert util date to sql date

```
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date4.getTime());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... Is there a way  is there a way to insert the field in the format of date ("dd-MON-YYYY") of type date?

Comment: From java side you just specify that its sql. Now its upto DB vendor, how to  represent that date. You need to check it for your DB vendor