# Timestamp to String to DateTime issues

Tags: java, datetime, jdbc, timestamp

I tried to see questions about date convert issues between two database using java but didn't solve my problem.

Here is the current date to insert in my database with a DateTime format :

```
    java.sql.Date SQLDateValue = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()) ;
    preparedStatement.setDate(index, SQLDateValue);
```

And here is the Timestamp from an API named Vdoc, convert to String and i tried to convert it to java.sql.Date (DateTime) :

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    java.util.Date DateValue = (java.util.Date) this.getWorkflowInstance().getValue(this.ListeChamps[i][2]);
    String StringDateValue = DateValue.toString();
    java.sql.Date SQLDateValue = new java.sql.Date (sdf.parse(StringDateValue).getTime());
    preparedStatement.setDate(index, SQLDateValue);
```

The second line return a field value containing a String but i need to use toString().

The following error message is :

```
    Failed to convert the date and / or time from a string.
```

Both of my date parameters are java.sql.date, i don't understand.
If you have an idea of ​​what happens with this, it would be nice to help me.

Ezerah

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Date.toString() do not what you expected. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530012/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date) how you can convert java.util.Date to java.sql.Date

Comment: *Why* do you think you need to convert the value to a string and back? What is the value in question?

Comment: tell me what : `this.getWorkflowInstance().getValue(this.ListeChamps[i][2])``return before instanciate it to DateValue ? Maybe the problem is from here

Comment: @uknowbigmams It returns an IWorkflowInstance, which is an object from the API. It is the value of a field and it's a timestamp date here

Answer (score 1):

Just construct the java.sql.Date from java.util.Date.

Call [`java.util.Date::getTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--) to extract the count of milliseconds from [epoch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)). Pass that count to constructor of `java.sql.Date`.

In your case below should work.

```
java.util.Date DateValue = (java.util.Date) this.getWorkflowInstance().getValue(this.ListeChamps[i][2]);
java.sql.Date SQLDateValue = new java.sql.Date (DataValue.getTime());
preparedStatement.setDate(index, SQLDateValue);
```

Comment: Still don't work because there is the same SQL error

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
java.util.Date DateValue = **sdf.parse(**this.getWorkflowInstance().getValue(this.ListeChamps[i][2])**)**;
String StringDateValue = DateValue.toString();
java.sql.Date SQLDateValue = new java.sql.Date (sdf.parse(StringDateValue).getTime());
preparedStatement.setDate(index, SQLDateValue);
```

You can't cast String to Date, you should parse it

Comment: No need to generate a string. Just extract the count of milliseconds from epoch of j.u.Date and pass to constructor of j.s.Date. See the [correct Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31742031/642706) by Alexander.