# converting java.util.date to java.sql.date

Tags: java, date

So I am trying to convert the `java.util.date` (Wed Mar 23 21:58:14 IST 2016) to java.sql.date. The output I am having by .getTime() is 2016-03-23. I want it to be in the form **date time** or so.

I am not getting the time in this. I want time also in the converted date.

```
java.sql.Date  sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert java.util.date to java.sql.date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530012/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date)

Comment: The toString() method of sql.Date only returns the date part.  Use SimpleDateFormat to format it in the format you want.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate, you can find the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530012/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date

Comment: thanks @Scott123180 , i got it though

Answer (score 2):

`java.sql.Date` is equivalent of sql Date type , i think you are looking for  `java.sql.Timestamp`

```
Date d = new Date();
Timestamp stamp =  new Timestamp(d.getTime());  
System.out.println(stamp); //2016-03-23 22:08:39.686
```

Comment: yes, its working but the thing is the dateType should be java.sql.Date so that I can set it to a preparedstatement using setDate. setDate expects java.sql.Date

Comment: `java.sql.Date` has the format `YYYY-MM-DD` , there's no time part you can have with it

Answer (score 0):

As per the JavaDoc of `java.sql.Date`, it has only Date and not Time.

> A thin wrapper around a millisecond value that allows JDBC to identify
>   this as an SQL DATE value. A milliseconds value represents the number
>   of milliseconds that have passed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000
>   GMT.
>
> To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values
>   wrapped by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by setting
>   the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the
>   particular time zone with which the instance is associated.

If you want the time also along with the date then you should be looking at `java.sql.Timestamp` instead.

Here is the code snippet:

```
java.sql.Timestamp sqlDateTime = new java.sql.Timestamp(utilDate.getTime());
```