# Cannot save date (mm/dd/yy) in database

Tags: java, sql-server, windows, date, netbeans

I am using `java.sql.Connection` and `java.sql.Date` to access the date here is my code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     if(jTextArea1.getText().equals(""))
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter the Expence Description. ");

else if(jComboBox4.getSelectedIndex()<1)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Select the Type.");

else if(jDateChooser1.getDate().equals(""))
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter the Date. ");

else if(jTextField3.getText().equals(""))
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter the Amount.");

else{
  try{
    con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project","root","1234");
    ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into work values(?,?,?,?)");
    ps.setString(1, jTextArea1.getText());
    ps.setString(2, jCom.getDate());boBox4.getSelectedItem().toString());
    ps.setDate(3, (Date) jDateChooser1.getDate());
```

But it gives error as

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
```

Can anyone give the solution for aforesaid?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530012/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date

Comment: Aside, `jDateChooser1.getDate().equals("")` will always return false since a date cannot be equal to a string.

Comment: You have a semicolon in the middle of a line of code: `…jCom.getDate());boBox4…`

Answer (score 2):

**ps.setDate(3, (Date) jDateChooser1.getDate());**

Instead of casting the date in the above code, convert util Date to sql Date as below :

```
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
```