# convert String to date using java 8 and format -> 'uuuu-MM-dd'

Tags: java, java-8

I want to convert from string to date using Java 8.

I can easily convert using `SimpleDateFormat` and `yyyy-MM-dd` format

```
   String startDate2="2017-03-24";
   SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
   System.out.println(new java.sql.Date(sdf1.parse(startDate2).getTime()));
```

**output:**
2017-03-24

```
   String startDate2="2017-03-24";
   SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("uuuu-MM-dd");
   System.out.println(new java.sql.Date(sdf1.parse(startDate2).getTime()));
```

But when I use `'uuuu-MM-dd'` instead of `'yyyy-MM-dd'`

**output :**
`1970-03-24`(wrong)

**now in Java 8**:

```
   String startDate1="2017-03-23";
   DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd");
```

But I don't know how I can get the date which would be sql date type same as above correct output.

Comment: Why you do not use the same pattern in Java8?

Comment: Jens can you provide exact output rather then judging because when i use 'uuuu-MM-dd' output is wrong

Comment: After your edit it is not clear what you want?

Comment: i want sql date type using java 8

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530012/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date

Comment: With `SimpleDateFormat`, `u` means day of the week, not year as with `DateTimeFormatter`.  See the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Also, you have no need for `java.sql.Date` if using a JDBC driver that complies with JDBC 4.2 and later. You can use java.time types with the `ResultSet::getObject` and `PreparedStatement::setObject` methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`java.sql.Date` has a static `valueOf` method that takes a Java 8 `LocalDate` so you can do:

```
String startDate1 = "2017-03-23";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd");

LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(startDate1, formatter);

java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(date);
```

Comment: Yes it is necessary to use LocalDate. Java 8 date/time classes won't convert directly to old style date classes

Comment: but  why SimpleDateFormat is giving wrong output when i use 'uuuu' instead of 'yyyy'?

Comment: Because 'u' means 'day number of week' in `SimpleDateFormat`. It only means year in `DateTimeFormatter`

Comment: @greg-449 No need for that formatting pattern. That pattern is defined by the ISO 8601 standard, and the java.time uses standard formats by default when parsing & generating strings. `LocalDate.parse( "2017-03-23" )`  You could even combine it together: `java.sql.Date.valueOf( LocalDate.parse( "2017-03-23" ) )`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you have a text in yyyy-MM-dd format and you want it in uuuu-MM-dd format. So you need two formats:

```
String startDate2="2017-03-24";
SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("uuuu-MM-dd");
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(sourceFormat.parse(startDate2).getTime());
String formattedAsDayOfWeek = targetFormat.format(date);
System.out.println(formattedAsDayOfWeek);
```

Bottom line is that `Date` contains a millisecond value. `java.sql.Date.toString()` uses the `yyyy-MM-dd` format regardless how you parsed it. `java.util.sql.Date` uses another format:  `EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy` with English `Locale`.

You can do other formatting with `DateFormat` -s.

I presume you need the `uuuu-MM-dd` format for inserting data to the database. What does **that** logic look like?

Comment: Tamas i have used 'uuuu-MM-dd' instead of yyyy-MM-dd  you can see this    https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns

Comment: @jitendravarshney your input date, ` String startDate2="2017-03-24";` is in `yyyy-MM-dd` format, as long as you use `SimpleDateFormat`. I.e. `SimpleDateFormat` is a subclass of `DateFormat`. On the other hand, you are trying to use `DateTimeFormatter`, which uses another set of pattern characters.

Comment: can you give me a example of 'uuuu-MM-dd' @Tamas

Comment: @jitendravarshney If you use `DateFormat` like `SimpleDateFormat`, then uuuu-MM-dd will be `0005-03-24`, but that's sort of meaningless.On the other hand, if you interpret if wit `DateTimeFormatter`, then `2017-03-24` is a good example.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t want a `java.sql.Date`. You want a `LocalDate`. Your SQL database wants one too.

```
    String startDate2 = "2017-03-24";              

    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(startDate2);
    System.out.println(date);
```

Output is:

> 2017-03-24

I am exploiting the fact that your string is in ISO 8601 format. The classes of java.time including `LocalDate` parse this format as their default, that is, without any explicit formatter.

You also note that we don’t need any explicit formatter for formatting back into `uuuu-MM-dd` format for the output. The `toString` method implicitly called from `System..out.println()` produces ISO 8601 format back.

Assuming that you are using a JDBC 4.2 compliant driver (I think we all are now), I am taking the way to pass it on to your SQL database from [this question: Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2):

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject ( 1 , date ); // Automatic detection and conversion of data type.
```

Refer to the linked question for much more detail.

The `java.sql.Date` class is poorly designed, a true hack on top of the already poorly designed `java.util.Date` class. Both classes are long outdated. Don’t use any of them anymore.

One more link: [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)