# how to convert java.util.Date to the format accepted by oracle?

Tags: java, oracle

i want to pass date as a parameter in my stored procedure which accepts date parameter. the date format my oracle db accepts e.g 10-JUL-17

now i tried

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
Date d = new Date();
String newdate = df.format(d);
System.out.println(newdate);
```

it prints 13-JUL-17 but as it is string my table won't accept this value. 
how can i convert it to the date datatype so that oracle will accept it.

Comment: `Date`s do not have a format. If you need a `Date` object for your Oracle db,  format is irrelevant. Maybe you have a problem with your Oracle code that you haven't posted.

Comment: maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31238011/4273199

Comment: Beside all the conversions others are suggesting you, I'd go marking the date as a query parameter (i.e. with `?`) and use the JDBC driver methods to provide the relevant Java object (i.e. Date, Timestamp, etc)

Comment: A [`DATE` does not have a format](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/2087/dates/6848/the-format-of-a-date); it is stored internally as 7- or 8-bytes representing year (2-bytes), month, day, hour, minute and second (1-byte each). The user interface you use (SQL/Plus, SQL Developer, Toad, Java, etc.) will typically apply a format to the date so that it is human readable but this is not done by the database. The format used by SQL/Plus and SQL Developer is the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter which is stored in the database but any user can independently change their own settings.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set an argument to the given date value, you should use the `setDate()` method of your `PreparedStatement` instance.

However this method needs a `java.sql.Date` instance, and if your date is a `java.util.Date`, then you have to convert it: `new java.sql.Date(java_util_date.getTime());`

EG:

```
try ( PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement( "SELECT * FROM table WHERE dat >= ?" ))
{
  ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date( System.currentMillis() ) );
  try ( ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery() )
  {
    while ( rs.next() )
    {
      // process the row in rs
    }
  }
}
```

### Edit

For stored procedure use the following syntax in the SQL query:

```
{call stored_procedure(?)}
```

Also, use `executeUpdate()` instead of `executeQuery()`, if your stored procedure does not return a `ResultSet`...
(If i remember correctly, there were some issues with the `call` keyword, especially with the case. So try `CALL` if `call` does not work...)

Comment: to me it doesn't matter if it's java.util.Date or java.sql.Date i just need to insert the current date in a 13-JUL-17 format

Comment: Java dates do not have a format, but they can be set to JDBC parameters.

Comment: how do i do the same thing with stored procedure?

Comment: @sagarlimbu Just use a CallableStatement instead of a PreparedStatement and set the bind parameters on that instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is no format for `Date` fields in Oracle. As long as the datatype of the DB field is `Date` and you are passing the value as `Date` it should work. If you are passing the date as a `String` then your `sql` will have to use the `TO_DATE` function to convert the value. Try converting your date value into `java.sql.Date` before passing it to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **TO_TIMESTAMP** that converts char of CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, or NVARCHAR2 datatype to a value of TIMESTAMP datatype.

Answer (score 0):

If You're using entity to bind your data, simple

```
@Column(name = "DATE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date date;
```

will do

Answer (score 0):

Use the `TO_DATE` function. For example:

```
INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE
  (NUMBER_FIELD, TEXT_FIELD, DATE_FIELD)
VALUES
  (1,            'ABC',      TO_DATE(:p1, 'DD-MON-RR'))
```

[You can find the docs for the TO_DATE function here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions203.htm#SQLRF06132) and the [documentation for date format strings here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212).

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with the other comments and answers suggesting:

- Formatting as a `Date` using `PreparedStatement` and `setDate()`
- Using other standard JDBC driver functions
- Being aware that all of this is locale dependent

However, some old Cobol programmers (who don't know anything about Java or `Date`) taught me that you **can** use a `String` of the format `DDMMMYYYY`.

The following would be acceptable to Oracle 11g, with the en-US locale:

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET date_field = '10JUL2017'
 WHERE id = 1;
```