# Conversion to java.sql.Date

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-parsing, date

I have a `String` as below which needs to be converted into `java.sql.Date` format:

`2017-08-31 01:40:00+00:00`

I am using below code and I can see date is only parsed as `2017-08-31` and not the entire string as above. Can someone please suggest?

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").parse(dateTimeStamp);

java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```

Based on the suggestion in the answers, I implemented below:

```
String dateTimeStamp = "2017-08-31 01:40:00+00:00";
java.text.DateFormat format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZZ");
java.util.Date date = format.parse(dateTimeStamp);
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
System.out.println("timestamp - " + timestamp);
```

But, am getting below error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-08-31 01:40:00+00:00"
        at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
        at com.eneco.mysqlsink.WeatherForecastSink.WeatherForecastTask.put(WeatherForecastTask.java:94)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:435)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:251)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:180)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:148)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:146)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:190)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert java.util.Date to java.sql.Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530012/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date)

Comment: What do you need a `java.sql.Date` for? If it’s for your database, please note that you can probably get (or already have) a newer JDBC driver that will let you retrieve `java.time.LocalDate` objects from the database and store the same type into it. If so, I recommend you scrap the outdated classes from `java.sql` and use the modern ones from `java.time` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.sql.Date` only provides the date.. You need to use `java.sql.Timestamp` to get both date and time.

```
java.text.DateFormat format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
java.util.Date date = format.parse("2017-08-31 01:40:00+00:00");
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
System.out.println(timestamp);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `hh` pattern, which corresponds to [**hour-of-am-pm** field](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (values from 1 to 12). As the input doesn't have AM/PM designator, this won't always work as expected. You must change it to `HH` (**hour-of-day**, with values from 0 to 23).

Also, to parse the offset `+00:00` you need to use the `X` pattern:

```
String input = "2017-08-31 01:40:00+00:00";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX");
// java.util.Date
Date date = sdf.parse(input);
```

The `X` pattern was introduced in Java 7. If you're using an older version, you can also set the UTC timezone in the formatter:

```
// "X" is not supported
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
// set UTC in the formatter
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
// java.util.Date
Date date = sdf.parse(input);
```

This is worse because you need to know the offset from the input and set it in the formatter. So it's better to use `X` if supported.

Then you can create the sql dates from the `java.util.Date`:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

But remind that if you just `System.out.println` the sql date or the timestamp, those will be converted to the JVM default timezone (giving you the impression that it's wrong: see [this article](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/) for more details).

Also, keep in mind that a `java.sql.Date` just [keeps the date fields](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/Date.html) (day/month/year), setting the hours to zero (so the `01:40` is lost). A `java.sql.Timestamp`, on the other hand, preserves the [whole UTC millis value](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timestamp/info).

---

## Java new Date/Time API

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1571265/7605325) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/7605325), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/7605325).

If you're using **Java 6 or 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, you'll also need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

First you parse the input to an `OffsetDateTime`, using a `DateTimeFormatter` to specify the format:

```
String input = "2017-08-31 01:40:00+00:00";

DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXXX");
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(input, fmt);
```

Then you can convert it to sql types. In Java 8, there are built-in methods to do it:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(odt.toLocalDate());
java.sql.Timestamp sqlTimestamp = java.sql.Timestamp.from(odt.toInstant());
```

In Java 7, the ThreeTen Backport has the `org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils` class:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = DateTimeUtils.toSqlDate(odt.toLocalDate());
java.sql.Timestamp sqlTimestamp = DateTimeUtils.toSqlTimestamp(odt.toInstant());
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include timezone identifier in your format

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZZ").parse(dateTimeStamp);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the `timestamp` just use `java.sql.Timestamp` instead of `java.sql.Date`!

The `toString()` method of the `java.sql.Timestamp` object should return the string as you needed.

Answer (score 0):

The format you are using is good but you loose Timezone offset.

If you want to consider TimeZone offset then please  use below format.

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").parse(dateTimeStamp);
```

**Result:**

> utilDate = Thu Aug 31 01:40:00 IST 2017

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssX").parse(dateTimeStamp);
```

**Result:**

> utilDate = Thu Aug 31 07:10:00 IST 2017.

I am running this code from India and there is offset of 05:30 Hours in timezone.