# How to retrieve data from database using a date

Tags: java, sql, jsp

I use a calendar to input a date in a jsp file

```
<sj:datepicker id="startDate" name="startDate" readonly="true" maxDate="d" changeYear="true"
                                                           buttonImageOnly="true" displayFormat="dd-M-y" yearRange="2000:2200" />
```

As output it give date like this `09-Nov-17`

But in the database the date looks like `09-NOV-17` as I used date data type.

I wrote the sql to find the data using data as follow

```
if (inputBean.getStartDate() != null && !inputBean.getStartDate().trim().isEmpty()) {
        where += " and c.startDate = '" + inputBean.getStartDate().trim() + "'";
    }
```

But it dose not filer the data from the database by search with the input date and also show no error. How can I over come from this.

Comment: are you not storing date as `Date` type in DB, and use `PreparedStatement`?

Comment: convert the date in DB date type and then use query.

Comment: Covert date to java.sql.date in query. Look this it might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530012/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date