# How to convert java.sql.Date to Days and Days to java.sql.Date in UTC using Java 8?

Tags: java

I am trying to convert java.sql.Date to Days and convert the Days back to java.sql.Date all in UTC but I believe I am off by one day.

I tried below my `millis1` and `millis2` are off by one day.

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestDate {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String str="2015-03-31";
        Date date=Date.valueOf(str);
        long millis1 = date.getTime();
        System.out.println(millis1);
        int days = getDaysFromDate(date);
        long millis2 = getDateFromDays(days).getTime();
        System.out.println(millis2);
    }

    public static int getDaysFromDate(Date date) {
        return (int)ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(Instant.EPOCH, Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime()));
    }

    public static Date getDateFromDays(int daysSinceEpoch) {
        return new Date(TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(daysSinceEpoch));
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert java.util.Date to java.sql.Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530012/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date)

Comment: It's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

When converting from milliseconds to days, and then converting back to milliseconds from days, you will lose data.

In your case `millis1` and `millis2` both equal the same amount of `DAYS` (16525), but `millis2` will have fewer milliseconds after the method calls because it doesn't take in account for the extra hours that were not counted as a `DAY`. The extra hours most likely came from leap years. 
When using `ChronoUnit.DAYS` the date should be equivalent at mid-day.

Comment: Any other way on how to do this?